# is it possible to set a value on the triggered by comment in hudson when building from the addressbar?

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson

We're going to trigger hudson builds from powershell using curl and the build url:
http://hudson:port/job/build?parameters...

now I'm wondering if we can somehow pass a parameter that will add to the "triggered by" description for the builds started by our scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to edit the "triggered by" info on the build summary page without writing your own Hudson plugin.  However, I like to add my own sections and badges to the build summary page with the [Groovy Postbuild Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin).  In your case, you could use curl to pass an extra parameter string when starting your Hudson job.  Then, you could have the Groovy Postbuild Plugin read that parameter and create a new icon + text string on your job's build summary page.  That info could be the custom "triggered by" description that you'd like.